# How to know when a view is actually displayed

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

I have a Gallery that displays multiple scrollable frames, each containing a complex layout.
One of these layout elements is a gauge-like custom view that should animate whenever it gets displayed - not just created.
So if I scroll to the layout containing this view once, then go back, then scroll there again - it should do its animation and the user should see it.

I didn't find an appropriate callback for that. What I've already tried is overriding:

onDraw

onLayout

onAttachedToWindow

onDisplayHint

onVisibilityChanged

Some of them are not called at all, and some are called only when the Gallery re-initializes the view - not when it is actually displayed.

Thank ahead!

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding `getView` on your Gallery's adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    /* trigger your animation on this view */
    return view;
}
```

There isn't an explicit contract for when `getView` is called, but it should be called when the view in question appears on the screen.

Comment: It isn't - Gallery has a way of caching past views, so this function doesn't indicate a display. I already override it to supply the views from my Adapter, so I checked that.

Comment: It may be that there isn't a strong distinction around when the view is displayed.